# Office 365 - Save Conflict error when upload Publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-online, cewp

I have some Publishing pages aspx. When I tried to upload file to Site Contents - Pages, I got error page popup like that:

"Sorry, something went wrong Save Conflict Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

In my aspx file have Content Editor Web Part. If I delete all html in in node or If i don't delete html I have to set src="" and href="", I can upload aspx file successfully.

Then if my html with src="path" and href="path" I always got Save Conflict error.

What do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds for the issue:

1. You could use the script editor web part to add the custom code.
2. You could save the html code into one file, upload the file to the document library and then type the link of the file in the content editor web part.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[SharePoint Online Step-by-step: Creating Content Editor webpart and associate with HTML.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35080.sharepoint-online-step-by-step-creating-content-editor-webpart-and-associate-with-html.aspx)

Comment: I want to use content editor web part. I tried second option but still i got same error.

Comment: You could consider using the second workaround.

Comment: I tried second workaround but getting same error.